# Add new item in Web part is not showing

Tags: web-part

I have this weird scenario where a user with contribute access is not seeing Add New Item button in web part. I tried to edit page change the toolbar option to full but of no use. Did anyone faced this kind of issue. Can some one help me with this .I am using SharePoint 2010. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you add image for more details?

Comment: I have uploaded the picture...it is a web part on a page and it should have add item option available for the users who are having contribute access but it is not showing for them. It is a default option in SharePoint. Thanks.

Comment: Is the user able to add an item from the ribbon?